# Using WMS which is private but publicly available. Is it legal?

Tags: wms, license

I recently came across a useful WMS with ranges of various cellular technologies. It is used on a webmap of a private company but a simple look into network activity allows you to see the service address. There is no mention whether the underlying service is for public use or not but it is unprotected. Is it legal to use such a WMS for own purposes?

Comment: where can we ask questions about the legality of using geospatial data sets if not here? In other words, why is this question off topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this is a good practice to always specify the licence, but it is not always the case. The default status of a dataset (if not explicitly mentionned) is often considered as "all right reserved". If you find a wallet on the ground it doesn't mean that it is yours. So if specific rights to use are not granted you should not consider this as an open data.

In your case, you know the company, so the best way to know is to contact them.